# How to debug an imported reactive variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, google-chrome-devtools

In all of my components, I `import state from './state'` to have a global state I can access from there. It is not a state-of-the-art state machine because it does not have mutations etc. but it is perfect for my small case.

`state` is defined as a `ref()` variable and I would like to be able to peek at its value during debugging.

I expected it to show up in the Vue tab in Dev Tools but only variables defined in a particular component are shown, not the imported one.

How can I debug that global reactive variable? (short of displaying it somewhere on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html). Pinia is the go-to store for Vue 3 projects. It is lightweight and also has no mutations.
Though an extra library might seem like an overkill for your small use case, the debugging it offers might be a compelling argument on its own.

If, for some reason, you want to avoid Pinia, you can implement your state as a [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#what-is-a-composable) and then destructure the desired variable from your state in your component's `script setup`. Then it should be visible in Vue's Dev Tools.

```js
const { myVariable } = useMyState()
```